# What about an "essi" tag?

Tags: discussion

"ESSI" stands for "Earth and Space Science Informatics" and identifies the overlap between Earth science and computer science (or use). It's a distinct field or discipline at the AGU conference.

What about an "essi" tag? I'd add one but don't see how.

Comment: (1) One can use `[tag:essi]` to create a link to [tag:essi], it's very useful :) (2) Whenever a tag is an abbreviation or acronym, please immediately create the tag excerpt and mention what it states for, to avoid confusion ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're creating or editing a question just type in the name of the tag you want to create in the tag box and then press space. That creates a new tag.

An ESSI tag sounds like a great idea!